# How to close Radix/Shadcn popover from inside of it

Tags: reactjs, radix

I have a shadcn popover and its content is several buttons. I want to close a popover once button is clicked. How can I do that?

https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/popover

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue while working with the chadcn Calendar component that use a radix popover. I managed to address this problem by implementing a state. Please note that I've omitted some code for brevity, but I'll provide you with the essential concept. Hope that help!

```js
export function Component() {

  const [calendarOpen, setCalendarOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
              <Popover open={calendarOpen} onOpenChange={setCalendarOpen}>
                <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                  
                    <Button
                      variant={"outline"}
                      className={cn(
                        "w-[240px] pl-3 text-left font-normal",
                        !field.value && "text-muted-foreground",
                      )}
                    >
                      {field.value ? (
                        format(field.value, "PPP")
                      ) : (
                        <span>Pick a date</span>
                      )}
                      <CalendarIcon className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
                    </Button>
                </PopoverTrigger>
                <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
                  <Calendar
                    mode="single"
                    onSelect={() => {
                      setCalendarOpen(false);
                    }}
                  />
                </PopoverContent>
              </Popover>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, as the Popover api doesn't expose any way to handle open state other than that `open` flag. This is also how shadcn does it - as can be seen in the code examples here https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/combobox#installation

Answer (score 7):

In the Radix UI library, there's a `<PopoverClose>` component available within the Popover module. To utilize it, you would first import the `Popover` component from `shadcn`, followed by importing the `PopoverClose` component directly from Radix UI. Your code would look something like this:

```
import { Popover, PopoverContent, PopoverTrigger } from "../ui/popover";
import { PopoverClose } from "@radix-ui/react-popover";

<Popover>
    <PopoverTrigger>Open</PopoverTrigger>
    <PopoverContent>
        Place content for the popover here.
        <PopoverClose asChild>
            <button>X</button>
        </PopoverClose>
    </PopoverContent>
</Popover>
```