Shadcn-ui / DatePicker - how do I hide the drop-down Calendar upon selecting a date
In the last 2 samples on the doc page, https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/date-picker, if you select a date, you need to click outside the drop-down Calendar to close it. How do you hide the Calendar drop-down upon selecting a date?
TIA

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77146027/832783 which applies to my question as well.

Based on this answer I have:
date-picker.tsx
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import {useState} from "react"
import {Calendar as CalendarIcon} from "lucide-react"
import {Button} from "@/components/ui/button"
import {Calendar} from "@/components/ui/calendar"
import {Popover, PopoverContent, PopoverTrigger,} from "@/components/ui/popover"
import {FormControl} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {DayPickerSingleProps, SelectSingleEventHandler} from "react-day-picker";

type DatePickerProps = {
    caption: string
    onSelectDate?: SelectSingleEventHandler
} & Omit<DayPickerSingleProps, "onSelect" | "mode">

export function DatePicker({caption, ...props}: DatePickerProps) {
    const [calendarOpen, setCalendarOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Popover open={calendarOpen} onOpenChange={setCalendarOpen}>
            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <FormControl>
                    <Button variant={"outline"}
                            className={"normal-case flex justify-between pr-1"}>
                        {caption}
                        <CalendarIcon/>

                    </Button>
                </FormControl>
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent align={"start"} className={"w-auto p-0"}>
                <Calendar mode={"single"}
                          onSelect={(day, selectedDay, activeModifiers, e) => {
                              if (props.onSelectDate) {
                                  props.onSelectDate(day, selectedDay, activeModifiers, e);
                              }
                              //console.log('setting calendar open')
                              setCalendarOpen(false);
                          }}
                          fixedWeeks
                          weekStartsOn={1}
                          captionLayout={"dropdown-buttons"}
                          {...props}
                />

            </PopoverContent>
        </Popover>
    )
}


Usage on a form:
<FormField control={form.control} name={"dob"}
           render={({field}) =>
               <FormItem className={"flex flex-col pt-2"}>
                   <FormLabel>
                       Date of birth
                   </FormLabel>
                   <DatePicker caption={!!field.value ? format(field.value, "PPP") :
                       <span>Pick a date</span>}
                               defaultMonth={field.value}
                               selected={field.value}
                               onSelectDate={field.onChange}
                               fromDate={dobFromDate}
                               toDate={new Date()}
                               captionLayout={"dropdown-buttons"}
                   />
                   <FormMessage/>
               </FormItem>
           }
/>

I had to introduce onSelectDate because otherwise the onSelect handler inside the component would not have been called. I am new to reactjs and I am not sure if there is another way to do this via listeners, for instance.
